# How can i get the rollback_to info from the python api?

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, kubectl

Like the command :'kubectl rollout history deployments dep_name', I can get the revision list for this deployment, like something :

```
kubectl rollout history  deployment taudit
deployment.extensions/taudit
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
3         <none>
4         <none>
```

I create the dep with :

```
k8s_apps_v1 = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
        resp = k8s_apps_v1.create_namespaced_deployment
```

And I update the dep with:

```
k8s_apps_v1 = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
        resp = k8s_apps_v1.replace_namespaced_deployment
```

And I use this Api to get the dep info:

```
k8s_apps_v1 = client.ExtensionsV1beta1Api()
    resp = k8s_apps_v1.list_namespaced_deployment(
```

But I get the rollback_to filed with value 'None'. As I show the info above, I have 4 revision for this dep actually. So, I not know how can i get the right info???

Answer (score 0):

help！！！
The doc link : [list_namespaced_deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1Api.md#list_namespaced_deployment)
The api "" response model link is : [ExtensionsV1beta1DeploymentList](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1DeploymentList.md)

And you can find the target filed by "items[i].spec.rollback_to".